# Google docs java api entry.getContent() returns null on pdf file

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

Trying to download docs from google docs and most of the files are ok, but on some pdf the entry.getContent() returns null.

Don't see any explanation to that behavior, how can I get uri for doc download if getContent returns null ?

Thank You and Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely those PDF files have been marked as not available for download from the Google Docs UI.

Comment: Tried to mark document to be not downloadable - seems that this is not the case, the document is downloaded without any problem